# Extracting new info from existing dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to create a column for runs scored by non striker after each ball in a cricket dataset but unable to do so. However i have created a column for runs scored by striker by following code:

```
df_balls['striker'] = df_balls.groupby(['inning', 'p1'])['bat_runs'].cumsum()
```

can someone tell me how can i do this ?

[image: This is how my data frame looks like]

I have tried the same code for non striker also but it doesnt work:

```
df_balls['non_striker'] = df_balls.groupby(['inning', 'p2'])['bat_runs'].cumsum()
```

But this code doesn't gave me the desired output
[image]